# Fitting a Regression Model to log-log distributed data

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I'm working on analyzing the performance of an algorithm under small perturbations to an input variable. I included some python code to help make my question more concrete, but in principle this is a question regarding variable transformations in regression analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

df = pd.read_csv("https://tinyurl.com/qulhd3w")

x = df.eps
y = df.dist

plt.loglog(x, y, 'x', label='Distance to Solution')

# Try for example, a linear model
func = lambda t, alpha, beta: alpha * t + beta

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
poly = np.poly1d(popt)

yfit = lambda x: poly(x)

plt.plot(x, yfit(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Generated by the code above]

My x variable seems to have a log distribution, as does my y variable. The association in the loglog plot seems somewhat sigmoidal, but linear for a large section of my domain so I thought I would start by trying to add a linear regression line.

I realize the data is fairly noisy, so naively I tried to start by performing regression on just the means.

```
means = df.groupby('eps').mean()
[x, y] = [means.index, means.dist]
plt.loglog(x, y)

func = lambda t, a, b, c, d: a * t**3 + b * t**2 + c * t + d 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, 10**x, 10**y)
poly = np.poly1d(popt)

yfit = lambda x: np.log10(poly(10**x))

plt.plot(x, yfit(x))
```

[image: Polyfit on means under exponential transform]

The results don't look great for exponential transform linear regression either. It doesn't seem like the regression is sensitive enough to the values close to 0. Should I try something like weighted least squares?

How do I need to transform my variables in order to perform a regression in this log space? I have tried to transform them by taking $10^x$ and $10^y$ to make them approximately linear, but have not had great results. Ideally, I might want to fit something like a logistic trend model, which could be achieved by replacing the "func" line with

`func = lambda t, alpha, beta, gamma: alpha / (1 + beta * np.exp(-gamma * t))`

Comment: And do you care about predictions or inferences?

Comment: And the link is not valid anymore

Comment: @Janosch I updated the link, it should work now. I care more about prediction, and plotting a reasonable fitted curve. I realize the data have a fair number of outliers, and I might look at if removing these results in a better fit. For now a basic fit that has accuracy at both ends of the domain suffices.

Comment: If you are open to using `R` and if the abrupt change around `x = 10^-2` can be regarded as a change point from a slope to a plateau, then consider using the R package `mcp` after log-transforming both your predictor and the outcome. Specifically: `fit = mcp(list(y ~ 1 + x, ~ 0), data = df)`.

Comment: There is a logarithmic distribution, not relevant to your problem. So when you write "I have a log distribution" I don't know what you mean, except perhaps "my data appear to be better analysed using logarithmic scales".  Also, you presumably took logarithms to base 10; you didn't raise your data to powers of 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points:

1. Your data are log-log scaled. So why don't you take the logs of them?
2. Since you expect a sigmoid function behind the data, why not trying fitting it to the data?

Below, I model your log-transformed data as a (scaled) difference of two softplus functions, $y = log(1+e^x)$, plus a constant term:

$$
y = log(1 + e^{\alpha_1 + \beta x}) - log(1 + e^{\alpha_2 + \beta x}) + C
$$

This is a sigmoid function whose linearly rising part can be made as long as necessary:
[image: Sigmoid function]

Here is my code:

```py
# first, log-convert the data:
x = np.log10(df.eps)
y = np.log10(df.dist)

plt.plot(x, y, 'x', label='log-distance to Solution')

# the function to fit:
# the difference of two scaled softplus, plus a constant term:
func = lambda t, alpha1, alpha2, beta, C : \
  np.log(1+np.exp(alpha1 + beta*t)) -      \
  np.log(1+np.exp(alpha2 + beta*t)) + C

# the initial guess for the function parameters:
p0 = [12, 6, 2, -4]
plt.plot(x, func(x, *p0))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0)

yfit = func(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x, yfit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

and the fitted curve (red) and the initial guess (orange):

[image: Curve fit]

You are, of course, free to try out other sigmoid functions, especially if you have theoretical reasons to assume a particular form. In this case, the function I used seemed appropriate because of the long linear part in the middle.

**Edit:**

And, of course, it is trivial to convert the fitted curve back to the original (non-transformed) scale:

```py
yfit_exp = 10**(func(np.log10(df.eps), *popt))
plt.loglog(df.eps, df.dist, 'x')
plt.loglog(df.eps, yfit_exp, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image: Curve fit on the original scale]

Comment: Thanks, I guess using a sensible first guess is quite important or the optimizer will not converge. I think this is the issue I had at first when trying to fit a linear or sigmoidal curve to the log transformed data.

Comment: Yes, but this curve is quite well-behaved, not too sensitive to initial parameters. You can try starting with `p0 = [0, 0, 0, 0]` and you'll still get a solution almost identical (relative difference ~= 1e-6) to the original one, visually indistinguishable from it. I think doing the modelling on the log-transformed values is significantly more important.